# Position-independent executables and ptrace

Tags: linux, gdb, ptrace

I would like to ptrace a PIE on Linux and e.g. break at a given instruction address. From disassembly, I have the relative address of the instruction - how can I find out the location the executable was loaded at so I can get the absolute address?

GDB is able to trace PIEs - how does it deal with this?

Comment: I believe the **platform** is somewhat important here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does it deal with this?

On Linux, the dynamic loader `ld-linux...` has a special function: `_dl_debug_state()`, which the loader calls just before and just after loading shared libraries, and just after setting a global variable: `_r_debug.r_state` to `RT_ADD` or `RT_CONSISTENT`.

A debugger can set a breakpoint on that function, examine `.r_state` and `_r_debug.r_map`, and in doing so discover which ELF binaries are loaded at which address.

This mechanism was used to discover where e.g. `libc.so.6` has been loaded long before `PIE` binaries were supported. A `PIE` binary is just a special case of a shared library, so the exact same mechanism works for it as well.

This begs the question: how does GDB discover where `ld-linux` itself has been loaded (so the breakpoint on `_dl_debug_state()` can be set). The kernel *tells* it via the auxiliary vector, `AT_BASE` entry. More info on aux vector [here](http://articles.manugarg.com/aboutelfauxiliaryvectors).